# Is it possible to Determine which OAuth Library to use?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

As now we have OAuth and OAuth2 protocol for the various services like Facebook, Twitter, etc. I would to know if it is possible to detect which Service uses which OAuth from the backend programming and hence proceed to use the best suited OAuth 1 or OAuth 2 class  library for the OAuth?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to read each service provider's(facebook, twitter, etc) API documentation and decide based on that

Comment: So, I suppose you are saying there isn't a dynamic way of determining it, right? I will have to check to ensure that Facebook is using OAuth2, and Twitter is fine with OAuth etc? And have to keep track on individual service provider's update, so see if changes have been enforced for the site to use OAuth2?

Comment: Exactly - anyway - they also have different method names and ways of calling things, you can not use the same code for 2 services